# Graphics Disk[] with a hole

Tags: graphics

I have a simple question I have no answer to - how do I create an `Epilog` in (for example) a `DensityPlot` that consists of a `Disk[]` with a hole with the inner radius being `r1` and the outer radius being `r2`? Imagine something like this:

```
Graphics[{{Gray, Disk[{0, 0}, 1]}, {White, Disk[{0, 0}, 0.5]}}]
```

However, this would hide the density plot in the "hole" (it would stay white). How to create such object as an epilog to a density plot, stream plot etc?

I had two ideas: first, if there is something like GraphicsDifference, that would be it: bigger Disk minus the smaller one creates the object I'm after. However, I found no such function.

Second: create a circle using a really thick line so that the inner boundary corresponds to `r1` and the outer to `r2`. However this would not scale nicely (i.e. using `ImageSize -> ...` during export would not preserve these radii).

Thanks.

Comment: `Annulus` was introduced in 10.2

Comment: Thanks, that's great! Exactly what I was looking for! I googled a lot of queries like "Disk with a hole", but nothing returned Annulus...I am sorry though. Just curious: how would you make a graphics with rectangular hole so that the hole is transparent (the plot is visible through it)? So as to keep to the spirit of the original question...

Comment: A disk with a rectangular hole or a rectangle?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

use region tools to construct more general figures (addressing comment):

```
r = RegionDifference[ Disk[{8, 8}, 2], Rectangle[{7, 7}, {9, 8}]];
Show[
 ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}], 
 RegionPlot[r, Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Red, 
  BoundaryStyle -> Black]]
```

or

```
ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 Pi}, {y, 0, 4 Pi}, 
 Epilog -> 
  First@RegionPlot[r, Frame -> False, PlotStyle -> Red, 
    BoundaryStyle -> Black]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is what I've been looking for! Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

Nowadays, `Polygon[]` supports holes. Using george's example:

```
hole = Polygon[MeshPrimitives[BoundaryDiscretizeGraphics[Disk[{8, 8}, 2]],
                              2][[1, 1]] -> {{7, 7}, {9, 7}, {9, 8}, {7, 8}}];

ContourPlot[Cos[x] + Cos[y], {x, 0, 4 π}, {y, 0, 4 π}, 
            Epilog -> {Directive[Red, EdgeForm[Directive[Thick, Black]]], hole}]
```

[image: disk with hole example]

Answer (score 2):

Use `BezierCurve` and `FilledCurve`. Just for fun.

```
c = 4/3 Tan[π/8]; 
pts = {{0, 1}, {c, 1}, {1, c}, {1, 
   0}, {1, -c}, {c, -1}, {0, -1}, {-c, -1}, {-1, -c}, {-1, 0}, {-1, 
   c}, {-c, 1}, {0, 1}};
Graphics[{Orange, 
  FilledCurve[{{BezierCurve[3 pts]}, {BezierCurve[
      2 pts]}, {BezierCurve[pts]}}]}]
```

[image]